# Balancing the Redox reaction by Half reactions

Tags: redox

I'm having trouble balancing this reaction using half reactions:
$$\ce{I2 + KOH -> KI + KIO3 + H2O}$$

I so far know that iodine is reduced when it forms $\ce{KI}$ (oxidation noumber decreases from 0 to -1) and oxidised in $\ce{KIO3}$ (the Oxidation number increases from 0 to 5).

Oxidation half: $\ce{I2 -> KIO3}$

Reduction half: $\ce{I2 -> KI}$

The potassium atoms on both halves seem to be the problem because they are only on the product side. When I balance the iodine atoms the $\ce{K}$ atoms aren't.

I've tried this several times and can't work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your problem simpler(equivalent of your problem) just balance this reaction:
$\ce{I2  -> I^{-} + IO3^{-}}$ in basic medium.

While balancing, the $\ce{OH-}$ on the LHS correspond to the number of moles of $\ce{KOH}$ and the $\ce{IO3-}$ on the RHS correspond to the number of moles of $\ce{KIO3}$ (the $\ce{K}$ is just a distraction).

Answer (score 4):

1- Determining   oxidation number, Oxidation and Reduction:
$$
\ce{
\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}+
\overset{\color{black}{(+1)}}{K}
\overset{\color{ black }{(-2)}}{O}
\overset{\color{ black }{(+1)}}{H}
->
\overset{\color{black}{(+1)}}{K}
\overset{\color{green}{(-1)}}{I}
+\overset{\color{black}{(+1)}}{K} \overset{\color{ blue }{(+5)}}{I}\overset{\color{ black }{(-2)}}{O3}+\overset{\color{black}{(+1)}}{H2}
\overset{\color{black}{(-2)}}{O}
}$$
When you look at the reaction: it is an auto-redox reaction, in which:

The atom$\ce{I}$: went from $\color{red}{(0)}$ to $\color{green}
{(-1)}$, it gains electrons, so it is reduced.

The atom$\ce{I}$: went from $\color{red}{(0)}$ to $\color{blue}{(+5)}$, it lost electrons, so it is oxidized.

2- Separate the redox reaction into two half-reactions: one for the oxidation, and one for the reduction

$$\text {Reduction half: } \ce{
\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}+
{KOH}
->
{K}\overset{\color{green}{(-1)}}{I}
}$$
$$\text {Oxidation half: }
\ce{
\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}+
{KOH}
->
{K}\overset{\color{ blue }{(+5)}}{I}{O_3}
}$$
3- Balance all elements except oxygen and hydrogen in both half equations:

$$\text {Reduction half: } \ce{
\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}+
2{KOH}
->
2{K}\overset{\color{green}{(-1)}}{I}
}$$
$$\text {Oxidation half: }
\ce{
\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}+
2{KOH}
->
2{K}\overset{\color{ blue }{(+5)}}{I}{O_3}
}$$
4- Add the appropriate number of water molecules to that side of the equation required to balance the oxygen atoms:

$$\text {Reduction half: } \ce{
\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}+
2{KOH} 
->
2{K}\overset{\color{green}{(-1)}}{I}
+2\ce{H2O}} $$
$$\text {Oxidation half: }
\ce{
\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}  +
2\ce{KOH}  + 4\ce{H2O} ->
2\ce{K}\overset{\color{ blue }{(+5)}}{I}\ce{O3}
}$$
5- Add the appropriate number of hydrogen ions to that side of the equation required to balance the hydrogen atoms:
$$\text {Reduction half: } \ce{
\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2} +
2\ce{KOH} + 2\ce{H+} 
->
2\ce{K}\overset{\color{green}{(-1)}}{I}
+2\ce{H2O}} $$
$$\text {Oxidation half: }
\ce{
\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}  +
2\ce{KOH}  +4\ce{H2O} ->
2\ce{K}\overset{\color{ blue }{(+5)}}{I}\ce{O3}+ 10\ce{H+}
}$$
6-  Use electrons ($\ce{e^-}$) to equalize the net charge on both sides of the equation:
$$\text {Reduction half: } \ce{
\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}+
2\ce{KOH} +2\ce{H+} + 2\ce{e-}
->
2{K}\overset{\color{green}{(-1)}}{I}
+ 2\ce{H2O}  } $$
$$\text {Oxidation half: }
\ce{
\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}  +
2\ce{KOH}  +4\ce{H2O} ->
2\ce{K}\overset{\color{ blue }{(+5)}}{I}\ce{O3} + 10\ce{H+} +10\ce{e-}
}$$
7- Make the electrons gained equal to the electrons lost:
$$\text{Reduction half: } \ce{
5\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}+
10\ce{KOH} +10\ce{H+} +10\ce{e-}
->
10\ce{K}\overset{\color{green}{(-1)}}{I}
+ 10\ce{H2O}  } $$
$$\text {Oxidation half: }
\ce{
\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}  +
2\ce{KOH}  +4\ce{H2O} ->
2\ce{K}\overset{\color{ blue }{(+5)}}{I}\ce{O3} + 10\ce{H+} +10\ce{e-}
}$$
8- Combine the two half-reactions:

$ \ce{5\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2} +
10\ce{KOH} +10\ce{H+} +10\ce{e-} + \overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}  +
2\ce{KOH}  + 4\ce{H2O} 
->
10\ce{K}\overset{\color{green}{(-1)}}{I}
+ 10\ce{H2O} + 2\ce{K}\overset{\color{ blue }{(+5)}}{I}\ce{O3}+ 10\ce{H+} + 10\ce{e-}  } $

9- Cancel out the electrons and anything that is the same on both sides then collect the things that is the same on the same side to form one balanced redox equation:
$$ \ce{6\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}+
12\ce{KOH}  
->
10\ce{K}\overset{\color{green}{(-1)}}{I}
+ 6\ce{H2O} + 2\ce{K}\overset{\color{ blue }{(+5)}}{I}\ce{O3}  }$$

10- Shorten the equation in a simplified form:
$$ \ce{3\overset{\color{red}{(0)}}{I2}+
6\ce{KOH}  
->
5\ce{K}\overset{\color{green}{(-1)}}{I}
+ 3\ce{H2O} + \ce{K}\overset{\color{ blue }{(+5)}}{I}\ce{O3}  } $$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little guide.

1. Start with determining "relevant" species (those that reduced or oxidized):
   $$\ce{I2^0 + K+ + OH- -> K+ + I- + K+ + IO3- + H2O}$$
2. Notice that you have $\ce{OH-}$ here, thus, you have *basic* conditions.
3. Half-reactions

   $\ce{I^0 -> I^-}$

   $\ce{I^0 -> IO3-}$

So, you should "compensate" oxygens in $2^{nd}$ reaction (either using water or $\ce{OH-}$, since your conditions are basic, you should use $\ce{OH-}$ and "add" water to the right to compensate for "new" hydrogens).

4. $\ce{I^0 + 6OH- -> IO3- + 6H2O}$

Usually you simply use twice as many $\ce{OH-}$ as "compensated oxygens". Here you have 3 of 'em, so you should use $\ce{6OH-}$.

5. New half-reactions, but with electrons so net charge is 0:

$\ce{I^0 + e- -> I^-}$

$\ce{I^0 + 6OH- - 5e- -> IO3- + 6H2O}$

6. Balance electrons so number of electons for each half-reaction is equal (by multiplication)

$\ce{5I^0 + 5e- -> 5I^-}$

$\ce{I^0 + 6OH- - 5e- -> IO3- + 6H2O}$

then add halves:$$\ce{3I2^0 + 6OH- -> IO3- + 5I^- + 6H2O}$$

7. Almost there! Don't forget about cations:

$$\ce{3I2 + 6KOH -> KIO3 + 5KI + 6H2O}$$

Equation is balanced :)

Comment: Quibbling I'd write the half cell as $\ce{I^0 + 6OH- -> IO3- + 6H2O + 5e- }$ to better conform how it will be written in standard reduction tables.

Answer (score 1):

convert it into ionic form = I2 + OH⁻ ⟶ I⁻ + IO3⁻

oxidizing number of I went from 0 ⟶ -1(I⁻) and +5 (IO3⁻)

There's an "OH⁻" in the equation, which means the reaction is carried out in a basic medium.

Separating the equation into oxidizing and reducing halves,

↪ oxidizing half: I2 ⟶ IO3⁻

↪ Reducing half: I2 ⟶ I⁻

Now balancing both halves,

↪ **O.H :  6H2O + I2 ⟶ 2IO3⁻ + 12H⁺ + 10e⁻**
(1. Balance the number of Iodines.  2. Balance oxygens by adding 6H2O because there's 6 Oxygens on RHS, then balance the Hydrogens on LHS by adding 12H⁺ on RHS, then balance out the charges by adding electrons.)

↪ R.H :  2e⁻ + I2 ⟶ 2I⁻
(1. Balance the number of Iodines.  2. since there's no oxygen, balance out the charges by adding electrons.)

Multiply the reduction equation by 5 so that the number of electrons in both halves gets cancelled out.

↪ **The new equation for R.H will be: 10e⁻ + 5I2 ⟶ 10I⁻**

combining both halves together,

↪ 6H2O + I2 + 10e⁻ + 5I2 ⟶ 2IO3⁻ + 12H⁺ + 10e⁻ + 10I⁻

Since the reaction is carried out in basic medium, add the appropriate number of OH⁻ to both sides, which will neutralize all H⁺ and convert them into water molecules.

↪ 12OH⁻ + 6H2O + 6I2 ⟶ 2IO3⁻ + 12H⁺ + 10I⁻ + 12OH⁻

↪ 12OH⁻ + 6I2 ⟶ 2IO3⁻ + 6H2O + 10I⁻  ..... ×½

↪ 6OH⁻ + 3I2 ⟶ IO3⁻ + 3H2O + 5I⁻

adding K to balance the final equation,

↪ **6KOH + 3KI2 ⟶ KIO3 + 3H2O + 5KI**

( hope that helps. )

Comment: Some listed procedures are so complicated I would be in danger of unlearning to solve such trivial tasks just in my head within few seconds. Enough is ability to operate with small integers and using "magical" equation n.m=m.n. // ON change by 1 and by 5, therefore the reverted ratio 5:1:  i.e. 5 KI + 1 KIO3. We then need 6 KOH and 3 I2.  // 3 I2 + 6 KOH -> 5 KI + KIO3 + 3 H2O // Finished.

Comment: I solved it here using redox rules. You can do it if that is comfortable for you. you gotta solve more equations to get used to it.

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.